# post forms with yahoo pipes?

Tags: post, yahoo-pipes

is it possible to submit forms with yahoo pipes?

i basically need to log in somewhere, and get some stuff from the members area of a website into a feed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this is not exactly programming related... I guess it is close enough.

No, logging into somewhere is impossible with Yahoo Pipes. Sending the username/password isn't even the only problem here.

The real problem is that most, if not all, web sites that require a log-in depend on a session cookie or something similar. Yahoo pipes can do a GET request, and that's about it. Even if it *was* possible to send your user name/password in the URL, you would not be able to use the session cookie, so subsequent requests would fail.

So... If you have access to a hosted web site somewhere: Write a small proxy script (in PHP or whatever is available) that does the login and fetches the data. Let Yahoo pipes read from your proxy page. But if you are that far, you can just as well produce RSS format right away. ;-)

Comment: That is what i feared. Thanks for confirming this for me.

Answer (score -1):

I did a pipe that can log in and extract info. is working ok on a simple web form using POST.